# Get connection resource in Cakephp 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp

Upgrading from cake 1.3 and in this cake 1.3 version I had access to the connection resource to pg_query, pg_put_line, etc.

This is a functionality that deals with big CSV data - cakePHP $model->save() is out of question - slow.

In cake 2.4 the connection property was removed from the datasource. And I couldn't find no method to get it and nothing on docs.

Using pg_query with null as connection is not working.

Comment: Yeah, it is slow - we have a SaaS and many people using - before upgrading to cake 2.4 we could use $datasource->connection: now they not only removed the property but did not put anything there to replace. We need the low level - validation is done on the CSV already - we cannot use cake model->save() - it is slow no matter what the framework fan boys says. I don't need to prove anything - just need an answer.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing the same issue with a different requirement I was using the datasource connection directly for a huge complex query.  After the upgrade I can no longer run it the way I was.

Comment: No, no answer anywhere. I had to refactor my method using pg_connect ... pg_close. That was my solution for now. I'm using pg_query to start a transaction - pg_query('BEGIN'); then pg_query('COMMIT');